# Solaris 10: installing ghostscript

Tags: solaris

I installed ghostscript-9.04 and its dependencies from sunfree and was receiving error for missing certain libraries. Then I removed the 9.04 version and installed ghostscript-9.04.1-sol10-x86-local.gz. and now get the following error now:liblcms2.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory. Is that another dependent package? Thanks

Comment: It would help if you tell from where did you get ghostscript, precisely.

Comment: I installed ghostscript-9.04-sol10-x86-local.gz from sunfree and also the dependencies.

Comment: I removed the 9.04 version and installed ghostscript-9.04.1-sol10-x86-local.gz. and now get the following error now:liblcms2.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the latest version, ghostscript-9.04.1-sol10-x86-local.gz.

Perhaps the issue you are experiencing is what caused the respin.

Comment: Thanks. The previous issue was resolved. However, have the following new issue: liblcms2.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory. Is that another dependency from the ones listed for 9.04-sol?

Comment: Then please update your question stating that new issue and explaining how you did resolve the initial one.

Comment: I removed the 9.04 version and installed ghostscript-9.04.1-sol10-x86-local.gz. and now get the following error now:liblcms2.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory

Comment: Updating doesn't mean removing the initial question. Now pottedporkproduct's answer looks partially irrelevant.

Comment: The issue is sunfreeware doesn't seem to freely display package dependencies any more. Do you have this information available ?

Comment: No, I do not. Is there a site that has an updated list of dependencies? I looked into opencsw site but, am not sure how to download a specific package like liblcms2_2 (which I assume is the missing link). Thanks

Comment: liblcms2 is likely in lcms2-2.2-sol10-x86-local.gz

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ghostscript from OpenCSW? The version is 8.71, but chances are it'll work. Do you need the newest version?

Answer (score 1):

The LIBIDN_1.0 bit is the SONAME, which is a version number inside of a shared object. What has probably happened is that you have a slightly different version of libidn.so.11 installed than the one that Ghostscript was compiled with.

If you are hand-rolling these packages, you might save yourself some hassle by installing the ghostscript packages from opencsw.org.

Comment: LIBIDN_1.0 is not a SONAME, libidn.so.11 is. In this case, libidn.so.11 has been found, but the versioned symbols  weren't found. You need another libidn.so.11 with LIBIDN_1.0 symbols.

Comment: Ah, got my terminology wrong, confused symbol name versus SONAME

Answer (score 1):

Install the pkgs from the Solaris 10 media?
system      SUNWgscr                         GPL GhostScript (usr)
system      SUNWgsfot                        GNU Ghostscript Fonts (Other)
system      SUNWgsfst                        GNU Ghostscript Fonts (Standard)